# "No module named 'openai'"

Tags: python, pip, openai-api, nomodule

My code won't run due to an error message in my terminal stating: "No module named 'openai'". It wasn't personally written by me, but taken from a .py file found on GitHub for a chatbot.

```
import openai

openai.api_key = "placeholder"

messages = []
system_msg = input("What type of chatbot would you like to create?\n")
messages.append({"role": "system", "content": system_msg})

print("Your new assistant is ready!")
while input != "quit()":
    message = input()
    messages.append({"role": "user", "content": message})
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=messages)
    reply = response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"]
    messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": reply})
    print("\n" + reply + "\n")
```

I have the openai package installed, as it shows up when typing `pip list`, and I have also tried various other methods like installing using `pip3` instead of `pip`, but the error remains the same. I have also looked at other posts online with people encountering the same problem, but even then no answers have actually worked so far.

Comment: It could be due to many things, are you using a virtual env? make sure the package is installed there. `pip freeze` will help you detect if the package is really installed or not. Also, you should check that the python interpreter is the one where the package is installed. Verify that the Python interpreter you are using in your terminal corresponds to the one where you installed the OpenAI package. Last, try reinstalling the OpenAI package using pip to see if it resolves the issue. You can do this by running `pip install openai --force-reinstall`

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is happen due to the improper installation.
Uninstall then reinstall will solve.

`pip uninstall openai`

Then upgraded pip.

`pip install --upgrade pip`

Then re-installed the openapi package.

`pip install openai`